# Push notifications not working in dot net MAUI when the app is inactive(completely closed)

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Am building  a dot  net MAUI android app, and  the app only receives FCM messages while in the foreground or background. When completely closed , the app fails to receive the notifications.

in the AndroidManifest.caml file , i have the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.companyname.internconnect">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true">

        <!-- Your other application settings and configurations go here -->

    </application>

    <!-- Add permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    
</manifest>
```

the following is the code am using : as a matter of fact , when i click the notification ,  am  navigated to a new page without any errors.the only problem is that the app fails to receive the notification in the Inactive state yet i have the service below , which i expect to receive the notification and push it seamlessly.Thanks for anyone willing to help me here.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Firebase.Messaging;
namespace InternConnect.Services;

[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);
        if (Preferences.ContainsKey(ApplicationConstants.DeviceTokenKey))
        {
            Preferences.Remove(ApplicationConstants.DeviceTokenKey);
        }

        Preferences.Set(ApplicationConstants.DeviceTokenKey, token);
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);

        if (message.Data.TryGetValue("title", out var title) &&
            message.Data.TryGetValue("body", out var body) &&
            message.Data.TryGetValue("page", out var pageName))
        {
            ShowNotification(body, title, pageName);
        }
    }

    private void ShowNotification(string messageBody, string title, string pageName)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName))
        {
            intent.PutExtra(ApplicationConstants.PageNameKey, pageName);
        }

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,
            ApplicationConstants.NotificationId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ApplicationConstants.ChannelId)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetChannelId(ApplicationConstants.ChannelId)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.appicon)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(ApplicationConstants.NotificationId, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

Comment: On what device did you test it? Have you tried it on other devices?

Comment: Am testing  on my  android phone(vivo 1901).

Comment: You can try testing on other devices to see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Issue resolved? i am facing some issue right now. could you give answer, if it is resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter->Application->name of your application->Battery->unrestricted
and it would work

Comment: it not working my self. i used same code above he mentioned.

Comment: Can you elaborate more specific where can be found this ,,Parameter->Application->name of your application->Battery->unrestricted"

Comment: I think if you can't find it it's because you don't have the same settings. I'm on a Samsung Note 20 Ultra, so I can't say better